# Python - How do i multiply 2 lists

Tags: python

I am trying to multiply and append 2 lists. I can't understand how it works.

```
xs = [1,2,3,4]
m = 3
t.append(xs[m])
return t
```

How does `([1,2,3,4] * [3]) = 4`?

Comment: Usually vector math needs a library as it is not built into the language.

Comment: Instead of voting down how about you just _edit the post_ people? His meaning was perfectly clear. In the future, click the `?` above the post box to get editing help -- the most important thing is to format your code. It also helps if you write it in a way that people can easily test it, and if you use proper capitalization and grammar. You don't need to sign your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Performing `i[j]` indexes the sequence `i` with the value `j`. If you want matrix multiplication then you should look at [NumPy](https://numpy.org/).

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4][3]
4
```

Comment: Thank You Oscar, NOW I get it really sry if my post was not in correct format of your rules, I received -2, my apologies I didn't know as i just joined, Thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the list multiplication, we cannot multiply two lists. We can multiply list by a number(Integer; -ve will do as well). Doing this you can repeat or replicate your list may times as:

> [1, 2, 3, 4] * 3   *OR*
>
> 3 * [1, 2, 3, 4]

will produce

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]